# Looping through the DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using DataGridView in vb.net. I would like to loop through a column
and when a certain condition is met go to the next cell down and copy that into a cell in another column.
So if I had `9, 1, 7, 66, 7, 9` in my first column, my second column would catch `66` and `9` the numbers that come after the specified `7`.
I have managed this in vba, but can't crack it in vb.net's datagrid. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for

**Before**

```
Column1  | Column2
-------------------
   9     |
   1     |
   7     |
  66     |
   7     |
   9     |
```

**After**

```
Column1  | Column2
-------------------
   9     |
   1     |
   7     |
  66     |   66
   7     |
   9     |    9
```

**Code**

```
  For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount() - 1
      'Check condition
      If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column1").Value = 7 Then
          DataGridView1.Rows(i + 1).Cells("Column2").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i + 1).Cells("Column1").Value
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: Hi equisde.Thanks for reply,how do I specify the column names in your code.For example Column1 and Column 2.

Comment: You can do it by replacing the column index by column name. See the edited answer.

Comment: Hi equisde,Great,there is only one slight peculiarity here.When I run the program it works fine with the numbers appearing in the new column,the only problem is the first number is appearing in the new column also.So for example in your example above Column 2 displays the number of all the numbers after number 7 (as required) but for some reason it places the number 9(first number in column1) into the first cell in Column 2.Any suggestions how to get round this much appreciated and thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I'm really stumped about it. Since it is a very very simple code and i cannot find out where is the line causing the error you mentioned, I've decided tested the code and i cannot reproduce that behavior. The above code is working fine. Really weird.

Comment: Hello equisde.Many thanks.I managed to solved the problem by placing -2 instead of -1 in the start of the for loop and it works just fine.Many thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Yep. It will skip the `NewRow` at the end. I had that property (`AllowUsersToAddRows`) disabled so it was not necessary. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if it helped. Happy coding! :)